# Attributes of type reference in C++

Tags: c++, oop, attributes

I am a Java developer. When I need to put a reference attribue in my class, I do this:

```
public class Account{
    private int num;
    private Person client;
}
```

But now, I have to do the same in C++

How can I do that in .h file?

Actually I just have the num attribute:

```
class Account{
    private:
            int num;
    public:
            Account(int num);
            ~Account();
            int getNum();
            void setNum(int num);
}
```

How should I put the Person attribute below and how should I compile it?
Thanks.

Comment: Depends. How will you use `client`? Consider pointer, reference, or smart ptrs.

Comment: Please describe your requirements in some way other than showing tiny snippets of code from a completely different programming language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are at least 4 ways of doing this:

1. Using a pointer (`Person*`), this is what most C and C++ programmers would probably do, but it is frowned upon by many for some good reasons. You need to take care of deleting the object when it is not needed any more (which may be non-trivial if several objects may reference the same object), and you must be sure a pointer is valid before using it (the dreaded nullpointer).
2. Using a **reference** (`Person&`), this will require you to initialize the reference when `Account` is constructed, and you cannot change it later during the lifetime of the object. Using a  reference, unlike a pointer, "looks like" using a normal variable.
   The restriction of not being able to reseat a reference could be a problem in your case, since it's conceivable that an account is taken by another person (say, if the original owner dies). In that case, you'd have to delete the `Account` object and create a new one in its place. On the positive side, a reference is guaranteed to be valid (unless you are particularly malicious and really try to trick the compiler).
3. Using a `shared_ptr<Person>`, if you want to have a reference-counted garbage collection not unlike what you have in Java too. Many `Account` objects can share the same `Person`, and when the reference count goes to zero, it is deleted.
4. Simply using a `Person`, this will make a **copy**, probably not what you want, except if each `Person` is only ever referenced by one `Account` (unlikely, people often have several accounts).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want, in C++ you have to say that more specifically than in Java where everything is a garbage-collected reference. You probably do not want the Account to "own" the client (so that for example, when the Account is deleted the corresponding person (or copy thereof) is deleted), so

```
class Account { Person client; /* ... */ };
```

is right out (if you do want Accounts to own their clients, then it's totally OK, do just that) So you probably want a pointer.

```
class Account { Person* client; /* ... */ };
```

Then the "owner" of the referenced Person is/should be responsible for it's deletion (and maybe also its creation) and has to ensure (i.e. it has to be ensured through your program's structure) that no dangling pointers to it remain when it is destroyed: That's exactly what ownership means, and this kind of thinking is probably new to you when you come from Java.

If you cannot determine a distinct owner of the Person, i.e. it has shared ownership, then use `std::shared_ptr<Person>` which is a reference counted smart pointer that will destroy the pointed-to-object when all `shared_ptr`s to it have been destroyed (if used correctly, it's the most similar thing to garbage collection you will get in standard C++, but bear in mind, that if you have cyclic references you need to break them manually with `std::weak_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

For a reference you probably want a Person * which is a person pointer to a person object. In java everything except primitives are references in c++ you can have values, pointers and reference objects(designated by an &). 
`Person * client;` is the code

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything special, really:

```
class Account{
    int num;
    Person client;
public:
    Account(int num);
    ~Account();
    int getNum();
    void setNum(int num);
};
```

This is creating an object (a value) not a reference, but it's not at all clear whether you really want/need a reference (i.e., you might, but then again you might not). Depending on the situation, it's possible you want `Person &client;` instead (though this is *rarely* desirable) or `Person *client;` (which creates a pointer, not a reference, but then again, Java's references are mostly "pointers in denial"). The basic difference between a pointer and a reference (as the terms are used in C++) is that a pointer can be assigned to, but a reference can only be initialized. That means (among other things) that if your `Account` class includes a reference member, it's likely impossible to support assignment of the Account class meaningfully. Pointers can be assigned.

Also, look over your `getNum` and `setNum` carefully to see whether they're really accomplishing anything useful -- if they're like the accessors/mutators in most Java, you're probably better off without them.

Comment: This is not a reference to a person like it would be in java